# Order by desc datetime field not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple SQL statement which grabs some news records and orders them by DESC.

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE title LIKE '%Ford%' ORDER BY pubDate DESC LIMIT 5
```

My PHP is below:

```
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE title LIKE '%Ford%' ORDER BY pubDate DESC LIMIT 5"); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
    {
       echo stuff
    }
```

The field pubDate is DATETIME and the result display earlier records and not the latest.

I have never had this problem before, any thoughts?

Comment: Make sure you are ordering by the same field you are displaying.

Comment: I am display pubDate as well as other fields.

Comment: I guess, your issue same bug with on `mysql.com` arround `datetime order by and limit` here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37964

Comment: Bit to tech for me that fix, when I copy and paste the query into PhpMyAdmin it brings back the correct results.

Comment: Prix: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.22, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: No body got any ideas other than the mysql bug?